# NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002 fix does not work

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am getting this error NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002. 
I have added the code below into my info.plist. Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
    <string>TLSv1.0</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Please include the actual code causing the error in your question.

Comment: It would be great if you can post more details like url

Comment: the status NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002 

as per the documentation Please check. your Intenet connection,

Comment: Check following answer

Comment: the full output i get is this from the console 2018-02-26 15:02:58.691626+0000 hello[4367:4078481] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework 2018-02-26 15:02:58.694082+0000 hello[4367:4078481] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework 2018-02-26 15:02:59.028870+0000 hello[4367:4078549] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002 report.pdf 

I am running on iPad with an wifi on?

Comment: Also I am not using an external link which is weird I am linking to an internal HTML document 


let pathToInvoiceHTMLTemplate = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "invoice", ofType: "html")

Comment: can you check first if the file is successfully accessible?

Comment: Hi Harshal, yes is is if I print HTML content it outputs the whole file

Comment: does your html calls any remote resourece??

Comment: THANK YOU! I feel so stupid now, the HTML doc had a call yes

Comment: FYI, `-1002` is `NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL`. Press command-shift-O, search for `NSURLError` (unselect "swift" option if you're working in Swift project), and you'll be taken to `NSURLError.h`, which shows you which codes are for which numeric values.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is about App Transport Security.Because your url is not https.Try to change like this in the info.plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

You can check all error codes and there meanings on following link

[NSError by NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nserror/)

Comment: Hi I have also tried that.. the full output i get is this from the console 2018-02-26 15:02:58.691626+0000 hello[4367:4078481] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework 2018-02-26 15:02:58.694082+0000 hello[4367:4078481] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework 2018-02-26 15:02:59.028870+0000 hello[4367:4078549] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002 report.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The status of error - code -1002 as per the documentation Please check. ,

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrorunsupportedurl?language=objc

please check the url once again with postman.

Comment: Hi I have also tried that..  the full output i get is this from the console 


2018-02-26 15:02:58.691626+0000 hello[4367:4078481] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-02-26 15:02:58.694082+0000 hello[4367:4078481] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-02-26 15:02:59.028870+0000 hello[4367:4078549] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
report.pdf

Comment: I had modified my answer plz check it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but my case was different. Here is the code that generated the error:

```
    if let url = URL(string: imageUrl){
        getDataFromUrl(url: url) { data, response, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                if let imageFile = UIImage(data: data) {
                    self.createItem(forModule: module, title: title, description: description, date: date, image: imageFile, table: table)
                } else {
                    self.createItem(forModule: module, title: title, description: description, date: date, image: nil, table: table)
                }
            }
        }
    } else { print("invalid url") }

private func getDataFromUrl(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        completion(data, response, error)
        }.resume()
}
```

Later I found out that imageUrl was not actually a url at all it was just a string, literally "false" thats it. and what made it worse that it was not caught in both else statements.

so I solved it by just adding the guard below:

```
if let url = URL(string: imageUrl){
        getDataFromUrl(url: url) { data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                self.createItem(forModule: module, title: title, description: description, date: date, image: nil, table: table)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                if let imageFile = UIImage(data: data) {
                    self.createItem(forModule: module, title: title, description: description, date: date, image: imageFile, table: table)
                } else {
                    self.createItem(forModule: module, title: title, description: description, date: date, image: nil, table: table)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I can call the createItem function and save my item without image successfully. 
So check your URLs carefully specially if you're getting them from an API.