# NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002 when retrieving and displaying images

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For anyone having this problem, who is not helped by this post, you may find the following use-full: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991149/nsurlconnection-finished-with-error-code-1002-fix-does-not-work).

Here is a copy of the error:

> 2018-08-29 18:39:59.458950-0400 proj[5319:3378682] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002

I have looked through these answer and not found anything to work. I believe its because the problem is happening for another reason for those. I am having the problem when fetching images from a database and trying to display them in on a image view.

Full code bellow:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

class PhaseOneViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var p1ImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func loadImages(_ sender: Any) {
        //p1ImageView.image = nil
        NKPlaceholderImage(image: UIImage(named: "placeholder"), imageView: p1ImageView, imgUrl: "\(Storage.storage().reference().child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("post\(takePicViewController().finalPost + PhotoArray.sharedInstance.numberPost)").child(ImageUploadManager().imageName))") { (image) in }

    }

    func NKPlaceholderImage(image:UIImage?, imageView:UIImageView?,imgUrl:String,compate:@escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
        
        if image != nil && imageView != nil {
            imageView!.image = image!
        }
        
        var urlcatch = imgUrl.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "#")
        let documentpath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        urlcatch = documentpath + "/" + "\(urlcatch)"
        
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile:urlcatch)
        if image != nil && imageView != nil
        {
            imageView!.image = image!
            compate(image)
            
        }else{
            
            if let url = URL(string: imgUrl){
                
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    () -> Void in
                    let imgdata = NSData(contentsOf: url)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        () -> Void in
                        imgdata?.write(toFile: urlcatch, atomically: true)
                        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile:urlcatch)
                        compate(image)
                        if image != nil  {
                            if imageView != nil  {
                                imageView!.image = image!
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have also asked These questions [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52069139/images-not-displaying-in-imageview#comment91112438_52069218), [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029400/firebase-saving-last-image-in-array-to-storage-twice), which may be of help to someone in my situation or to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting the image by past that URL in the browser?

Comment: I am not sure... But what i know is that data is nil when I run it so i belive the answer is yes

Comment: That means there is no any image on that URL. Please Check by passing this URL in  function and let me know that you are able to load this image. https://s15.postimg.cc/u2yt13na1/personal.png?dl=1